# Lock sing on mp3 files when edited from Songbird

Tags: windows-7, id3, songbird

Everytime I edit (Metadata id3 tags) of mp3 files in Songbird, the icon of mp3 files changes, an LOCK sign gets added on top of cover art of the fileicon when viewed in Windows Explorer. What does the lock sign means? How do I remove it?

Here are other details of my system:
OS: Windows 7 Home Premium
Songbird: 1.9.3 (Build 1959)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lock usually appears on files that have come from another computer. It is to alert you that they may possibly be infected and so to use them with caution.

But I have no idea why they appear on your current files after editing. In any case, the lock will disappear on its own soon. If the first page of the file's Properties say that it is blocked, unblock it and Apply.

Comment: Thanks Abraxas. File properties do not show that it is blocked. I will check back again to the file if the lock sign disappears automatically after sometime.

Comment: Just to experiment i copied the lock files to different directory, removed the original files and copied back... now no lock sign on these files!!! I dont understand how this works. Atleast your answer helped me with some solution. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I admit tht when the lock will appear is sometimes seemingly arbitrary. It does not appear on all downloads. But it is an added NTFS stream that makes the lock appear and it can be removed if it bothers.